# Solution for a readonly copy of a standalone MongoDB server

Tags: replication, mongodb, mongodb-4.0, read-only-database

I store some data in many databases/collections on a standalone MongoDB server. This server is used for production.

I need to access those data (or at least nightly build data, and not all databases/collections), for data analysis purpose : readonly, possibly high consumption queries. I don't want to operate data analysis on the production server.

For now, I use `mongoexport` and `mongoimport` to export and re-import the data into another standalone server. This has many drawbacks :

- indexes are not kept,
- night export/re-import is a long-time process that may fail,
- data is not continuously synced (not absolutely necessary).

I studied the MongoDb replica set documentation, but some questions are still unanswered to me :

- Can I choose which databases/collections are replicated ?
- Is a 2-members (a primary and a secondary) replica set eligible ?
- Can I make our production application servers "always" read-write on the primary, and our data-analysis server "always" read on the secondary ?

I know I have many questions and it might break Stackoverflow Q/A principles, but I hope the question label could be useful for many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I choose which databases/collections are replicated ?

A replica set is a group of mongodb instances that [maintain the same data set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/#replication-in-mongodb), so it is necessary for the entire set of data to be replicated between nodes.

> Is a 2-members (a primary and a secondary) replica set eligible ?

A replica set should have an [odd number of voting members](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/#deploy-an-odd-number-of-members). If you want to maintain only two data-bearing nodes, you would want to include an [arbiter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-members/#replica-set-arbiters) in the replica set as a third voting member.

> Can I make our production application servers "always" read-write on the primary, and our data-analysis server "always" read on the secondary ?

All writes must be directed to the Primary node of the replica set; clients are [not allowed](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-secondary/) to write to a data bearing node in the 'Secondary' replica set state.

Specifying a [read preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) is a good way of directing queries to different nodes of a replica set.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those useful informations !

Comment: Adding: Reads are allowed on secondary, but they can be delayed results.